# Bing Map Windows Phone 7 Pinching

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I have a map view that works well, pinches to zoom in and out and pan around.

I then call a detail page...

```
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

And then go back to the map pressing the back button.  After that pinching is disabled to zoom in or out.  I can double tap or pan around but this doesn't seem right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a legend at MS the October 2010 Dev tools update fixed it!

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49b9d0c5-6597-4313-912a-f0cca9c7d277&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't been confirmed as a bug, but has been reported.. as yet without a response. You could bump the thread though. Alternatively, raise a connect ticket to ensure it's getting visibility, referencing these posts.

[Bing Map Control loses Pinch Zoom functionality](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/66366.aspx)

Comment: Hey Mick, I saw that post.  I will raise a Connect ticket, just got to work out how!

Comment: connect.microsoft.com, prod vs, wpd tooling